# Redirection with self.location.href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my application and when the user click on it, I want the page be reloaded. This is my button :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline add_sol">Ajouter</button>
```

It calls a javascript function :

```
 $(function() {

    $(".add_sol").click(function(){

        var e = document.getElementById("select_sols");
        var sol = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        var string = window.location.pathname+"_ajouter_sol"+window.location.search+"&id_sol="+sol;
        alert(string); //The alert displays the right adress

        self.location.href(string);

    });
});
```

I did an alert with the `string` variable and it displays what I want. But I don't know why the `self.location.href` doesn't work.

Comment: window.location.href = xxxx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `window.location.href` - should work perfectly

Comment: it is not a function like `window.location.href(...)` but a property of the window object, so change it like `window.location.href = string`

Answer (score 2):

Use can `location.reload();` to refresh your page

or `window.location = string;` for a redirect

Comment: I don't want to reload the page, I want to redirect :/

Comment: then use `window.location = "newurl";`